# Construction of a projection operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, diagonalization

Is it possible to construct a projection operator (which is not the identity operator) for a given space? (e.g.  $\mathbb{R}^4$)

Comment: Sure.  A diagonal matrix with any combination of 0's and 1's on the diagonal is a projection matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if the vector space is finite dimensional.  For let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $\Bbb F$, and let $W \subset V$ be a subspace.  Say $\dim V = n$ and $\dim W = m \le n$.  Choose a basis $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_m$ for $W$ and extend it to a basis for $V$ by adding $l = n - m$ linearly independent vectors $v_i$, $1 \le i \le l$, $v_i \notin W$ for all $i$.  Define a map $P: V \to V$ by the rules

$Pw _i = w_i \tag{1}$

and

$Pv_i = 0; \tag{2}$

extend $P$ to all of $V$ by linearity; thus, since any $y \in V$ may be written

$y = \sum_1^m a_iw_i + \sum_1^l b_i v_i,\tag{3}$

where the $a_i, b_i \in \Bbb F$, we have

$Py = \sum_1^m a_i Pw_i + \sum_1^l b_i Pv_i = \sum_1^m a_iw_i \tag{4}$

by the definition of $P$.  It follows from (3) and (4) that if $y \in W$, so that all the $b_i = 0$, that is

$y =  \sum_1^m a_i w_i, \tag{5}$

that

$Py =  \sum_1^m a_iw_i = y; \tag{6}$

furthermore, for any $y  \in V$ as in (3) we find *via* (6) that

$P^2y = P(Py) = P(\sum_1^m a_iw_i) = Py, \tag{7}$

i.e.,

$P^2 = P, \tag{8}$

the definitive trait of projection operators.

The preceding discussion in fact provides a recipe for the construction of a projection onto a subspace $W$ of ***any*** finite dimensional vector space $V$ over ***any*** field $\Bbb F$.  For example, if $V = \Bbb R^4$ and $W$ is he subspace spanned by the two vectors

$w_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \tag{9}$

and

$w_2 =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \tag{10}$

we may take

$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \tag{11}$

and

$v_2 =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}; \tag{12}$

if we set

$Pw_i = w_i, i = 1, 2, \tag{13}$

and

$Pv_i = 0, i = 1, 2, \tag{14}$

it is easy to calculate  for any vector

$y = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ y_4 \end{pmatrix}, \tag{15}$

we have

$Py =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ y_2 \\ 0 \\ y_4 \end{pmatrix} \in W; \tag{16}$

one may also easily verify $P^2 = P$ for this $P$; it is indeed a projection operator.

Finally, it is worth noting that, though our example was taken with $V = \Bbb R^4$, a parallel result holds with $V = \Bbb F^4$, $\Bbb F$ any field; and similarly, more general examples may be had looking at $V = \Bbb F^n$ for any positive integer $n$; the reader may use our recipe to construct many projections.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your arguments don't require the space to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:  I restricted myself to finite dimensions to avoid issues of the meaning of infinite sums of basis vectors and usually convergence in some norm or other.  There are undoubtedly analogous results in Banach/Hilbert spaces etc.  The problem is how to add an infinite number of vectors, starting with what is essentially a *binary* operation.  You can repeat yourself a *finite* number of times, but need some notion of topology or convergence to tackle infinite sums as far as I can tell.

Comment: Infinite-dimensional vector spaces do not involve infinite sums (it is not even possible to discuss them, without a topology). Your answer still holds if you remove the words "finite" and "dimensional".

Comment: @MartinArgerami:  OK, agreed, and I actually considered writing it up along those lines.  I'm actually very engaged with inifinte-dimensional vector spaces from a purely algebraic point of view, *sans topologie*.  But as I mentioned, infinite sums require some form of special handling, and it just seemed too complicated to go there.  The problem is that I've made extensive use of bases, which require sums of the form $y = \sum a_i w_i$  What does this sum mean if the $w_i$ form an infinite basis, without *some* notion of how to handle the infinite sum.

Comment: If you've got any leads on the above from the web or the literature or your own ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:  specifically, what is to be done with equations like three in the event $m = \infty$ or $l = \infty$?

Comment: Algebraic infinite-dimensional vector spaces do not require infinite sums of any kind. As a trivial example, consider the space of polynomials and the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$. And, if you assume Choice, Zorn's Lemma guarantees that any vector space has a basis. So, as I said, if you remove the words "finite dimensional" from your answer, it still holds, in any vector space, **without using infinite sums of any kind** (or, if you want, in a way where every infinite sum has only finite many nonzero coefficients).

Comment: @MartinArgerami:  good answer.  I hadn't thought about Choice and Zorn in this context, though they clearly are germane.  I'll think about this and try to get back to you before too long.  Thanks.